# bump or increment the integer that is a result of grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im grepping below file with output below but i want the result to increment it with another number.

```
egrep -i --color=auto "[0-9]{10}" file
2017080802 ; Xen number
```

How can I make it to **2017080803** at least?

Comment: 2017080802 is the output of grep command, right?

Comment: try this: `echo "$(($(egrep -i --color=auto "[0-9]{10}" file)+1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
awk '/[0-9]{10}/ { print 1+$1 }' file
```

Comment: yes this one work.  can you explain what happened in the bracket {print 1 + $1 },  what is $1.  anyways thanks a lot. great way.

Comment: @error467 In awk, `$1` refers to the first field (separated by spaces or tabs) on the line. If the numbers might appear somewhere else on the line, you'll need something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{$1=($1+1); print $0}' file` will increment your first column in output.
Exmpl:
`a="2017080802 ; Xen number"; echo $a | awk '{$1=($1+1); print $0}'
2017080803 ; Xen number`